# How to build a web service to detect content change(s) at an external website?

Tags: web-services

I'm researching ways to build a web service to periodically traverse a predetermined list of web pages (of another external website) to detect if a page's content has changed from

1. editing of the page, and
2. deletion of the page.

The end goal is to have this web service post push-notification events to mobile devices.

FYI, I've searched and read "Questions with similar titles" here.

Thank you for sharing your answers.

Comment: Can you share your current research? I feel that your question is too open ended for programmers as it stands.

Comment: I don't think you really want a web *service*, since you're not actually providing a service.  This type of program would be more of a periodic task or cron job.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was looking at the problem as a web service because this service (to monitor an external website) will then initiate push notifications to an app on a mobile phone.

Answer (score 2):

What about just reading the page with cURL? Maybe store a checksum of what you read and compare against that next time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking of a checksum solution but thought I'll seek alternative approaches before deciding.

Answer (score 2):

Editing of the page can be checked by:

1. Check if the HTTP header `last-modified` is present. If it is, compare it to the previously stored value and you are done.
2. If the `last-modified` HTTP header is not present, store the page checksum or checksum of the important part of the page. Since some of the web pages contain randomly generated parts, you want to ignore these parts. You can define the *'important part'* of the page using e.g. regular expression. Next time you will compare the stored checksum with new one.

Delete of the page can be checked simply by trying to connect to it.

Comment: Many web servers, web applications, and even proxies by default set the last-modified to NOW or don't implement it (properly) at all - so the page is ALWAYS changed.